# Import an txt file into python with several different types of data. How do I make every line in the data file into an instance of my class?

Tags: python

I recently started coding in python, and am now attempting to take a text file, in which there are data values for size, price, and brand of specific types of clothing. I've already managed to import it the text file with all its info using this:

```
    def buyshop():
        print("You have selected to buy clothing. What would you like to buy?")
        print("\n Articles available: \n")
        handle = open("Clothing Shop On Sale.txt", "r")
        reading = handle.read()
        reading =(re.sub("'|(|)", "", reading))
```

I'd like to take the data in the file which usually would look something like this raw:

```
~24 adidas    bad       blue      2695  
~12 adidas    excellent white     2200
```

An informal schema of this data:

- Size (3 digits max)
- Brand (10 characters max)
- Condition (10 characters max)
- Color (10 digits max)
- Retailprice (6 digits max).

I will index it out using specific spaces for specific data in each line. New sets of data are shown by the `~`. How do I take this data and create an instance of my class per set of data?

Comment: If you're trying to eliminate parens, you need to escape them.

Comment: You really need to show us how to create a new instance of your class, and probably an input sample with more variations (what's the `~` for if it's really this simple?)

Comment: Could you show some of the attempts you've made so far?

Comment: The color seems to be a string, not a number.

Comment: `instances = []; with open(filename, 'r') as lines: for line in lines: instances.append(NewObject(*line.lstrip('~').rstrip('\n').split()))`

Comment: Which class? There isn't any

Answer (score 0):

In best practive, it's recommand to have one type of data per file

For the first part, you can use `csv` module for help you.

```
import csv

with open("shop_file", "r") as fd:
    a = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=' ')
    result = [line for line in a if line] #remove empty line
```

result = `[['~24', 'adidas', 'bad', 'blue', '2695'], ['~12', 'adidas', 'excellent', 'white', '2200']]`

For the second part, you can use regex or use json for manage more easily your data.

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading the file using readline() function use the following code to get values to the variables

```
line='~24 adidas bad blue 2695'.lstrip('~') #removes the leading '~' 

size,brand,condition,color,price=line.split() #use line.split('\t') if you use tab to seperate the values
```

make sure you put this in a try-except block